# How do I prove $B_{q} \neq \emptyset$.

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Suppose that $\mathbb P$ is the uniform distribution on $[0,1)$. Partition the interval $[0,1)$ into an equivalence class such that $x\sim y$ ($x$ is equivalent to $y$) if $x-y\in\mathbb Q$, the set of rational numbers.

> (a) Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.
>
> (b) Show that $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1)$ is an equivalence class.
>
> (c) Find $(\pi/10 + 5/6) \pmod 1$ up to $10$ decimal places.
>
> (d) Given a subset of $A$ of $[0,1)$ and $x\in[0,1)$, define $A_x = x + A = \{(x+a) \pmod{1} \;|\;a\in A\}$. Then $A_x\subset[0,1)$.
>
> (i) Show that ${\pi\over10} + \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1)$ is an equivalence class.
>
> (ii) Show that $x+\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1)$ is an equivalence class for any $x\in[0,1)\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Ive already answered problem 1 a-d. Now i must prove 2 part a) I'm stuck.

> Given $1$, by the Axiom of Choice, there exists a nonempty set $B\subset[0,1)$ such that $B$ contains exactly one member of each equivalence class. Prove each of the following:
>
> (a) Suppose that $q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1)$. Show that $B_q\ne\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$ is nonempty, and $B_q$ is just a translation of $B$ by $q$.

Choose $x \in B$. Then $x + q \mod 1 = x+q - n \in B_q$ for some integer $n$.

Comment: Yes, i understand that it is a translation, but i am having a hard time figuring out how to put that into words to prove that it is nonempty

Comment: If you have an element, and you translate that element, it is still an element. It can't disappear.

Comment: so this would just be a straight forward proof?

Comment: it just follows from since B is not empty then B_q is nonempty since B_q=x+q?

Comment: Yeah. It's really immediate